# How do I use php so that when a user presses a specific button, they can write to a specific .txt file?

Tags: php, chat

Basically, as in other questions I've asked related to my php chat application, I am trying to get it so that there is a text field where $msg is displayed via msg.txt. Two users can communicate to another in this way. This would be easy if I wanted to use a simple include function. But I don't want to take all the trouble to make and upload all those pages to my server. So how can I have it where when the user, say named Aaron, clicks on a button titled Benjamin, and types to a file called aaronbenjamin.txt, and if Aaron wants to talk to another user, he can press on a button titled Chris, and type to a file called aaronchris.txt? And all from the same box and text field? Thanks, I appreciate it.

EDIT: This is my code-

http://key-mail.zxq.net/msg.txt

Comment: firstly welcome, do you know how to use php to create and write to a file. why not use a database?

Comment: yes, but SQL isn't working for me so I'm using a .txt.  I do know how to do that, but the problem is not writing to a database, it's the idea of clicking different buttons on the same page to get it to write to different databases.  Make sense?

Comment: I'm kinda sorta new to php.  However, is there something similar to an OnClick type of thing?  Where, suppose, a specific button is clicked in html, then a specific action happens using php contacting the server?  If so, what is the basic syntax for such a function?

Comment: Would I need to use AJAX?  And if so, how?

Comment: Read my post if you wish to do this without AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should learn about [using forms with PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp), with regards to your comment. If you read that tutorial fully, it should answer all of your questions about forms and php.

As far as getting it to write to a different text file, since you seem worried about "uploading all those pages", you'll be happy to know there's an easy solution!

There's a function called [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), which will create or write into a file.

Since you're new(ish) to PHP, here's an example:

```
<?php

$file = 'hello.txt';
$text = 'Hello World!';

file_put_contents($file, $text);

?>
```

This puts the contents of the `$text` variable into the file with the name stored in `$file`.

Reading from a file is similarly easy, with [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Assuming the file `hello.txt` exists from before and has the same contents, you can use the following code to read from the file and output its contents:

```
<?php

$file = 'hello.txt';

echo(file_get_contents($file));

?>
```

That will show the contents of $file.

Now, moving into the specifics of your question, if your form sets a "to" and a "from" GET variable where "to" is your username already, then the following code would write the value in a "message" GET variable into the file based on the pattern you gave:

```
<?php

$to = addslashes($_GET['to']);
$from = addslashes($_GET['from']);
$msg = addslashes($_GET['message']);
//addslashes is used as a small security measure

$file = $to . $from . '.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $msg);

?>
```

This fetches our variables from the GET array, sanitizes them to some extent, sets the file name, and writes the message to the file.

If you have any questions about specific parts of this or you'd like me to go into more detail, please feel free to ask!

Comment: I wish there was a 'like' button on here :)

Comment: The up arrow is the equivalent of "like" :-)

Comment: it says I need to build up my reputation.  how do I do that?

Comment: And if the answer solves your problem, press the check mark below the up arrow to mark it as the right answer!

Comment: @Matthew Upvotes from others on your own question is an easy way to gain rep

Answer (score 1):

This is how to write to a file:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

You're better off to use a database tho for sure.

To make different links do different things, you can use AJAX as you suggested or you can use GET variables to route functions on the PHP side. The latter is easier but means you will need to reload the page after the user presses the button.

here's a little demo:

```
<a href="thispage.php?clicked=1">click here</a>
```

then at the top of the page in php:

```
 if($_GET['clicked']==1){--write to file1---}
 else if($_GET['clicked']==2){--write to file2---}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: No need for fopen, doesn't that overcomplicate a simple `file_get_contents`?

Comment: In my experience file_get_contents often causes permissions errors especially when working on a local server. It depends on the specific server setup. fopen is not that difficult anyway is it?

Comment: `file_get_contents` is just a convenient wrapper for `fopen`/`fread` - you'll always get the same permissions errors for the two of them.

Comment: I've yet to have permission errors from file_get_contents. If it does give an error, try CHMOD 0777 instead of 0644 which it probably is.

Comment: @Cyclone DANGEROUS! You're asking to be hacked. I'm speaking from experience!

Comment: @cronoklee Setting file permissions to 0777 is certainly not 'dangerous', for someone to write to the file they'd have to have a script on your server, and if you're letting users run erroneous code then you've got a bigger problem than 0777 file permissions. Your being "hacked" most likely had absolutely nothing to do with file permissions.

Comment: Actually it was other developers on the same shared server. suPHP was not installed and PHP was running under user 'nobody' so it seems the hacker could simply write a script that accesses my account from his account. Installed a trojan which google found and blacklisted my site. What a mess.

Comment: Hopefully you guys notice this; I tried the two scripts, and both failed to succeed despite my earlier euphoria.