# Re-ask: How do I use php so that when a user presses a specific button, they can write to a specific .txt file?

Tags: php, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use php so that when a user presses a specific button, they can write to a specific .txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574371/how-do-i-use-php-so-that-when-a-user-presses-a-specific-button-they-can-write-to)

First of all, am I able to re-ask a question?  I got two answers, yes, but I tried both and they didn't work.  I'm worried that people will forget about my question and I might not ever get the answer to my question and patch up my code.  Anyway, here it is.  If, however, re-asking questions is against some rule I was not aware of, I will refrain from this in the future.  Thanks!

> Basically, as in other questions I've asked related to my php chat application, I am trying to get it so that there is a text field where $msg is displayed via msg.txt. Two users can communicate to another in this way. This would be easy if I wanted to use a simple include function. But I don't want to take all the trouble to make and upload all those pages to my server. So how can I have it where when the user, say named Aaron, clicks on a button titled Benjamin, and types to a file called aaronbenjamin.txt, and if Aaron wants to talk to another user, he can press on a button titled Chris, and type to a file called aaronchris.txt? And all from the same box and text field? Thanks, I appreciate it.

The most important thing about my question was that the user is able to press the name of another user and they will be able to chat with the user.  This means that they will be switching to a different .txt file whenever they click on a user.  Thank you to @Cyclone and @cronoklee for your answers, but sadly they didn't work.

Comment: can you tell me the flow of your application?

Comment: Simply edit your question to say that neither answer worked. Also, if you accepted an answer, then  un-accept it. Making changes to your question brings it back to the top of the list.

Comment: 1. Can you post some code (I get what it is you're trying to do, I just wanna know how far you tried). 2. You do realized that if you have one user called Aaron and one user called Chris... but also one user called AaaronC and another user hris... you might have issues?

Comment: Reasking questions is only ok if you show that you adapted the answers. If you are aksing vaguely, don't show your tried approaches and just want a second tutorial, then your question will get closed again.

Comment: thanks, I won't do it in the future

Answer (score 1):

Use this for the buttons:

```
<textarea name=msg></textarea>
<input type=submit name=file value=Aaron>
<input type=submit name=file value=Benjamin>
```

And this for the PHP:

```
$fn = preg_replace('/\W+/', '', $_REQUEST["file"]);
file_put_contents("$fn.txt", $_REQUEST["msg"]);
```

Comment: ugh.  none of these are working.  I'll post the code;